# MessageNotConsumedException is thrown if cancel Masstransit's Mediator request

Tags: masstransit

I have set up a Masstransit's [Mediator](https://masstransit-project.com/usage/mediator.html) instance and I am getting responses like this:

```
try
{
    var client = mediator.CreateRequestClient<GetOrderStatus>();
    var response = await client.GetResponse<OrderStatus>(command, cancellationToken);
    // ...
}
catch (Exception ex)
{    
    Log(ex.ToString());
}
```

If `cancellationTokenSource.Cancel()` is called (by pressing the Cancel button in the UI) during getting the response, I get

**MassTransit.RequestException: An exception occurred while processing the GetOrderStatus request ---> MassTransit.MessageNotConsumedException: loopback://localhost/response => The message was not consumed**

Is it expected behavior? I thought it should throw `TaskCanceledException` or `OperationCanceledException` so I could handle the cancellation properly.

Comment: While technically correct, the message was not consumed if it was cancelled before being handled by a consumer, it does lead to a confusing experience since it would make sense that a TaskCanceledException be thrown instead.

Comment: I'd suggest creating an issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit) to track it.

Comment: Issue created, same issue as the other question: https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/issues/2114